# How do I access the child node values in my XML document?

Tags: xml, delphi, xml-parsing, delphi-2009

I have a XmlString which contains multiple elements with their nodes.

ie

```
<Element>
    <AccountName>My Account Name</AccountName>
    <FullName>Edward Jones</FullName>
</Element>
```

I can access the Node names ie AccountName, FullName, but I can't access the values or they return blank.  Here is my code.

```
Doc : IXMLDocument;
begin
  Doc := XMlDoc.LoadXMLData(XmlString);  
  Doc.DOMDocument.getElementsByTagName('Element').length;  // = 11  
  Doc.DOMDocument.getElementsByTagName('Element').item[2].childNodes[0].nodeName;  // = AccountName  
  Doc.DOMDocument.getElementsByTagName('Element').item[2].childNodes[0].nodeValue; 
end;
```

There are 11 instances of the 'Element' in my XmlString so this checks out, the nodeName = AccountName which is what I expect.  But the nodeValue is blank.  Is there another way to pull the values?  Does anyone know why the node values are blank?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A guess: It looks like standard DOM API, so you could have a Text-node below the element nodes.

```
Doc.DOMDocument.getElementsByTagName('Element').item[2].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

Answer (score 3):

You are dropping down all the way to the low-level DOM level.  In that regard, @MizardX's response is correct - the text is contained in its own distinct child node that you have to access directly. However, since you are using `IXMLDocument`, you don't need to drop that far down.  The `IXMLNode` interface is higher up and hides those details from you, providing easier access to nodes and their data, eg:

```
var
  Doc : IXMLDocument; 
  ElementNode, AccountNameNode, FullNameNode : IXMLNode;
  Count: Integer;
  NodeName, NodeText: String;
begin 
  Doc := LoadXMLData(XmlString);   
  ElementNode := Doc.DocumentElement;
  Count := ElementNode.ChildNodes.Count; // = 2

  AccountNameNode := ElementNode.ChildNodes[0];
  NodeName := AccountNameNode.NodeName;
  NodeText := AccountNameNode.Text;

  FullNameNode := ElementNode.ChildNodes[1];
  NodeName := FullNameNode.NodeName;
  NodeText := FullNameNode.Text;
end;
```